# Igraph - Multiplex networks - How to colour edges by edges's attributes (more than 2 different colors)?

Tags: r, igraph

Very simply, I just want to represent a multiplexed graph and color the links according to their type (variable of an attribute of the links attribute table).

I read several topics on the forum where there are two possible types of links (so two possible colors) but in my case I have 7 possible.

I guess it's a basic syntax question but I can't answer it alone as I'm a beginner. I hope someone can help me

I tried two methods but they don't work.

**The first one works but not what I wantonly : allows to query one type of link**: only for "cohab" are colored. Now I want the "cohab" to be in orange, the "copol" in red, the "C" in green, etc. and if missing values, in grey.[image: method 1 where only one type of link is colored]

```
plot(net, edge.color= c("grey", "orange")[(E(net)$type=="cohab")+1],vertex.size=15,
     vertex.color="gray40",layout=layout_in_circle, edge.curved=.3)
```

**The second one doesn't works.** [image: inaccurate and incomplete visualization (method 2)]

```
colrs <- c("gray50", "tomato", "gold", "orange","blue","black","green") 
E(net)$color <- colrs[E(net)$type]

plot(net, edge.color=colrs,vertex.size=15,
     vertex.color="gray40",layout=layout_in_circle, edge.curved=.3)
```

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.  In particular, code should be complet, including all inputs, so anyone else can copy it from the question, and paste it into their R session to run it.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the edge attribute to a factor, then numeric, then use this as the index for the `colrs` vector

```r
colrs <- c("gray50", "tomato", "gold", "orange","blue","black","green") 

plot(net, edge.color = colrs[as.numeric(factor(E(net)$type))],
     vertex.size = 15,
     vertex.color="gray40", layout = layout_in_circle, edge.curved=.3)

legend(0.95, -0.5, legend = levels(factor(E(net)$type)), col = colrs, lwd = 1)
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
library(igraph)

set.seed(1)

df <- expand.grid(from = LETTERS[1:22], to = LETTERS[1:22])

net <- graph_from_data_frame(df[df$from != df$to,], directed = FALSE)

edge.attributes(net) <- list(type = sample(c('cohab', 'copol', 'C', 'D',
                                             'small', 'large', 'crazy'), 
                                           gsize(net), TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! First time on the forum and I am impressed by your responsiveness and help. I tested and understood the process of coloring the edges. Not really though for the second part after "set.seed"; I guess it's to calibrate the visualization interface but don't understand the different steps... if you ever have 1minute to explain? Thanks :)

Comment: Last question, with this method how are the colors assigned to each type? In the order they appear in the attribute table? Nothing to specify for NA?

Comment: @NA_ You don't need the second part. That's just the data that I created to make a graph similar to yours, since I don't have your actual data. I had to create a data set that would be similar enough to yours so that the code would work on your data but also produce an output on my machine. To do this I had to infer what your data was like from the clues in your question (22 nodes, each with a link to every other node). Just ignore the second block; it's to demonstrate how I created the data set for my example.

Comment: @NA_ the unique values in the `type` attribute are assigned a factor level. This is done in alphabetical order, since that is the default when creating a `factor`. You can specify the order however you like though - check `?factor` to see how to do this. When factor levels are converted to numeric, they just become integers. These are used as indexes into the `colrs` vector.